# Python script execution in Android

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, android-ndk, chaquopy

I have used gradle plugin chaquopy to execute python script in android but getting this exception.

**com.chaquo.python.PyException: OSError: This platform lacks a functioning sem_open implementation, therefore, the required synchronization primitives needed will not function, see issue 3770.**

Please review the Gradle code below. Please share if any modifications are required. I can share the logs also.

defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.pythonsample"
minSdkVersion 24
targetSdkVersion 30
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"

```
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            python {
                srcDirs = ["src/main/python"]
            }
        }
    }
    python {
        buildPython "/usr/local/bin/python3"
        buildPython "python3"
        pip {
            install "pyserial"
            install "multiprocess"
            install "threaded"
            install "supyr-struct"
            install "times"
            install "queuelib"
            install "optspec"
        }
    }
}
```

Any solution to resolve this error and run the sem_open in Android?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full stack trace and the relevant sections of your Python code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [com.chaquo.python.PyException: ImportError: This platform lacks a functioning sem\_open with multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65589550/com-chaquo-python-pyexception-importerror-this-platform-lacks-a-functioning-se)